# Apollo-GraphQL error when sending word with space?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have a GQL Apollo which filters by a state. The GQL takes values like "ACCEPTED" or "DECLINED" etc.
However, I noticed that when i send a filter like "GOOD LEAVER" which has a space it won't work anymore. Any ideeas?
I get this error

```
Stack: GraphQLError: Variable "$stateIn" got invalid value ["GOOD LEAVER"].
In element #0: Expected type "MemberStateType", found "GOOD LEAVER".
```

to send this variable i am using a util function to take the values from props, the function is

```
stateIn:
  getFilterProp('status') &&
  getOr([], 'status', selectedFilterOptions).map(({ name }) =>
    toUpper(name)
)
```

I am 100% percent the value gets send because I can see them in the networks tab, it just throws the above error when I want to use the filter "GOOD LEAVER", otherwise, it works just fine.

Comment: This is a query!

Answer (score 0):

From the context, I'm assuming the type of your `$stateIn` variable is `[MemberStateType]` and that `MemberStateType` is an enum. As the error indicates, `GOOD LEAVER` is not a valid value for this enum. Enum values must be valid GraphQL names, so they must match the following regex:

```
/[_A-Za-z][_0-9A-Za-z]*/
```

However, the point is not that you're passing in a name with a space -- the point is that you're passing in a value that doesn't match the possible values for the enum as it's defined in the schema. If you passed in a value like `FWaFJRYyTPx` or some other invalid enum value, you'd see a similar error.

Consult the schema for the GraphQL endpoint to determine the valid enum values and transform your input accordingly.